# How to handle multiclass with Stratified Cross Validation in sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import time

params = {
    'min_child_weight': [1, 5, 10],
    'gamma': [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5],
    'subsample': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
    'max_depth': [3, 4, 5]
    }



xgb = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=600,
                silent=True, nthread=1)

folds = 5
param_comb = 5

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle = True, random_state = 1001)

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, param_distributions=params, n_iter=param_comb, scoring=['f1_macro','precision_macro'], n_jobs=4, cv=skf.split(X_train,y_train), verbose=3, random_state=1001)

start_time = time.clock() # timing starts from this point for "start_time" variable
random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
elapsed = (time.clock() - start) # timing ends here for "start_time" 
variable
```

My code is above, my y_train is a pandas series with multiclass with integers from 0 to 9.

```
y_train.head()
1041    8
1177    7
2966    0
1690    2
2115    1
Name: Industry, dtype: object
```

Once I run the setup code above, I received error message as:

```
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead.
```

I did some search on other similar questions, I tried to use `cross_validate` from   `sklearn.model_selection` and tried to use other metrics compatible with multiclass but still got the same error message.

Is there anyway I can do gridsearch on parameters with stratified cross validation based on performance metrics?

Update: After fixing the `dtype` issue, I want to pass multiple metrics into `scoring=`, I tried in this way because I read this document (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter):

```
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, param_distributions=params, n_iter=param_comb, scoring=['f1_macro','precision_macro'], n_jobs=4, cv=skf.split(X_train,y_train), verbose=3, random_state=1001)
```

Then I failed with following warning:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-67-dd57cd97c89c> in <module>()
 36 # Here we go
 37 start_time = time.clock() # timing starts from this point for 
"start_time" variable
---> 38 random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
 39 elapsed = (time.clock() - start) # timing ends here for "start_time" variable

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, 
**fit_params)
609                                  "available for that metric. If 
this is not "
610                                  "needed, refit should be set to 
False "
--> 611                                  "explicitly. %r was passed." % 
self.refit)
612             else:
613                 refit_metric = self.refit

ValueError: For multi-metric scoring, the parameter refit must be set 
to a scorer key to refit an estimator with the best parameter setting 
on the whole data and make the best_* attributes available for that 
metric. If this is not needed, refit should be set to False explicitly. 
True was passed.
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please show the dtype and some samples from the `y_train`

Comment: @VivekKumar I have updated it.

Comment: Why is dtype object here? Are there any strings in it? Can you try converting it to int by using `y_train = y_train.astype(int)`?

Comment: @VivekKumar I fixed it, now `y_train` is an inetger series. However, I want to use multiple metrics passed into `scoring`, but I failed due to some errors.

Comment: @VivekKumar It seems like I need to predefined a scorer which should includes all metrics I want then passed it to `scoring`. I tried this too but still received some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written [here in user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#specifying-multiple-metrics-for-evaluation):

> When specifying multiple metrics, the refit parameter must be set to
>   the metric (string) for which the best_params_ will be found and used
>   to build the best_estimator_ on the whole dataset. If the search
>   should not be refit, set refit=False. Leaving refit to the default
>   value None will result in an error when using multiple metrics.

Since you are using multiple metrics here:

```
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, param_distributions=params,
                                   n_iter=param_comb, 
                                   scoring=['f1_macro','precision_macro'], 
                                   n_jobs=4, 
                                   cv=skf.split(X_train,y_train), 
                                   verbose=3, random_state=1001)
```

The RandomizedSearchCV will not know how to find the best parameters. It cannot choose best scores from two different scoring strategies. So you need to specify the scoring type you want it to use to find the best parameters.

For that you need to set the `refit` param to one of the options you used in `scoring`. Something like this:

```
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, param_distributions=params,
                                   ...
                                   scoring=['f1_macro','precision_macro'], 
                                   ...
                                   refit = 'f1_macro')
```